# Count with subselect really slow in postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, indexing

I have this query:

```
SELECT c.name, COUNT(t.id)
FROM Cinema c 
JOIN CinemaMovie cm ON cm.cinema_id = c.id
JOIN Ticket t ON cm.id = cinema_movie_id
WHERE cm.id IN (
    SELECT cm1.id
    FROM CinemaMovie cm1
    JOIN Movie m1 ON m1.id = cm1.movie_id
    JOIN Ticket t1 ON t1.cinema_movie_id = cm1.id
    WHERE m1.name = 'Hellboy' 
        AND t1.time >= timestamp '2019-04-18 00:00:00'
        AND t1.time <= timestamp '2019-04-18 23:59:59' ) 
GROUP BY c.id;
```

and the problem is that this query runs really slow (more than 1 minute) when the table has like 20 million rows. From what I understand, the problem seems to be the inner query, as it takes a long time. Also, I have all indexes on foreign keys. What am I missing ?

Also note that when I select only by name (I omit the date) everything takes like 10 seconds.

**EDIT**
What I am trying to do, is count number of tickets for each cinema name, based on movie name and the timestamp on ticket.

Comment: Please explain what you want the code to do.  Sample data and desired results can help.

Comment: I edited my question

Comment: Have you tried using `BETWEEN` instead of `>= timestamp` and `<= timestamp`?  How does that affect things?

Comment: @saritonin: There's absolutely no difference between `>= and <=` and `BETWEEN` both are just syntax variations.

Comment: @dnoeth: Thanks for the info!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't understand why you are using a subquery.  Does this do what you want?

```
SELECT c.name, COUNT(t.id)
FROM Cinema c JOIN
     CinemaMovie cm
     ON cm.cinema_id = c.id JOIN
     Ticket t
     ON cm.id = cinema_movie_id JOIN
     Movie m
     ON m.id = cm.movie_id
WHERE m.name = 'Hellboy' AND
      t.time >= '2019-04-18'::timestamp and
      t.time < '2019-04-19'::timestamp
GROUP BY c.id, c.name;
```

Comment: Whoa :O Thank you very much :) I think I should learn a bit more sql before asking